# How do priorities work for jobs?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

In Oxygen Not Included, the Job Board allows a player to assign "Jobs" to the Duplicates (workers). This allows workers to gain experience doing various tasks, and with enough experience, they "Master" the job, which unlocks new jobs for them and gives them stat/skill boosts.

One can set the priority of the Job Board, but I do not understand what effect it has on the game. If I set its priority to 9, does that mean that all Duplicates assigned to a job will perform that specific Job, even though there may be other errands/tasks to do?

Answer (score 2):

The priority system is completely separate from the job board. The job board just increases stats and gives perks, it doesn't mean they'll prioritize the job.

Maybe this quote will help you to understand answer:

> Errands can be prioritized 1-9 (1 is lowest priority, 9 is highest). High priority errands are always performed before low priority errands. **However, a busy Duplicant will continue to work on their current errand until it's complete, even if a higher priority errand becomes available.**
>   [source](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Errand)

**Important:**
This is currently valid for Occupational Upgrade(v254439 and later).

Comment: What is the purpose of setting the job board’s priority?

Comment: @jvriesem you want to make sure only your artist paints paintings